# Pandas plot correlations

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I have been trying to plot pairwise correlations for stocks over time using python. I am following the following [repository](https://github.com/silburt/Machine_Learning/blob/master/Stock_Correlation/StockCorrelation.ipynb) but I can't seem to make the rolling correlation work, I get an error here:

```
correls = correls[(window-1):,:,:]

TypeError: '(slice(99, None, None), slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None))' is an invalid key
```

Adding a sample code:

```
todays_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
index = pd.date_range(todays_date, periods=10, freq='D')
 
columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
 
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
df = df.mask(df.isnull(), np.random.uniform(3, 331, size=df.shape))

window = 2                            #rolling correlation window length
correls = df.rolling(window=window).corr()
correls = correls[(window-1):,:,:]
```

Kind regards

Comment: Could you post a sample dataframe and sample code that you used. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you try to remove rows with NaNs in the end. To do it, try

```
correls = correls[(window-1)*len(df.columns):]
```

instead of

```
correls = correls[(window-1):,:,:]
```

Comment: Thanks Maria, that works fine, I guess the problem is the dimensions of "correls" output. if I wanted to select the correlation between A and B, the code below wouldn't work? 

sA = "A"
sB = "B"
correls.loc[:,sA,sB].plot()